# How to convert ".png" depth images into ".pfm" in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have depth images from a dataset that are in PNG format, but the Neural Network I need to use accepts PFM format depth images. I have searched over the internet, but could not find any proper answer with an explanation.

The PNG depth images have 3 channels with shape 640x480x3 16-bit depth image. I need to convert this PNG depth image into PFM image of 960x540.

[PNG Depth Image to be converted to PFM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7WEL.png)

[Image Values and Shape, printed as Numpy Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6WLg.jpg)

I used OpenCV to read PNG files and then tried to save them in PFM format which gave Null values.

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. show your attempts. -- OpenCV supports PFM (portable float map) so in principle it should work...

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is understanding the 3-channel PNG. @lashari0 you should upload some data we can inspect.

Comment: Looking at the source code, 1 and 3 channel images are supported by the PFM encoder. Data type doesn't seem to matter, everything is automatically converted to 32bit floats. This is assuming your OpenCV is at most ~4 years old, seems like there were some issues before that.

Comment: The PNG you have shared appears to be a single channel image, not 3-channel?

Comment: If you see the shape of the image in 2nd image, it shows a 3D Numpy Array.

Comment: I do see that, but that information cannot naturally come from the image you actually shared because the image is 640x480x1. So either imgur changed your image when uploading it (which is possible) or you did something weird in your code. So it would help if you showed a proper [mcve] and/or shared your actual image using something like Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: A depth image is also very unlikely to be 3 channel since it shows only one variable... distance. Some might be 4-channel, i.e. RGB+Depth, but 3-channel would be weird IMHO.

Comment: Maybe you didn't specify `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` when you opened the image with `cv2.imread()` ?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that, now openCV is reading image as a single channel. The PFM file is now correctly being converted.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project!

Comment: 640x480x3 to 960x540 does not make much sense. The aspect ratios are not even compatible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was doing an inference on another model. That model takes images 960x540.
PS 640x480x3 was a mistake on my part which was cleared. The depth images are in fact 640x480.

Comment: Not better ! ...

Answer (score 0):

First, read the depth image from OpenCV as Unchanged.

```
depth_PNG = cv2.imread('imageName.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Just save the depth image in the desired format with cv2.imwrite.

```
depth_PFM = cv2.imwrite('newName.pfm', depth_PNG)
```

Comment: What about the sizes ?